# Segmentation fault when reading C-style string from scanf

Tags: c++

I have following simple code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

struct Pacient {
int ill_state;
int ev_num;
bool operator==(const Pacient& other) const {
    return ill_state == other.ill_state && ev_num == other.ev_num;
}
bool operator<(const Pacient& other) const {
    return (ill_state < other.ill_state) || (ill_state == other.ill_state && ev_num > other.ev_num); // má menšiu prioritu, ak čaká kratšie (vyššie číslo na kartičke pri vstupe do ambulancie
}
bool operator>(const Pacient& other) const {
    return (ill_state > other.ill_state) || (ill_state == other.ill_state && ev_num < other.ev_num);
}
};

int main() {
char* ccmd;
std::priority_queue<Pacient> ps;
int ev_num, ill_state;
while (std::scanf("%s", ccmd)) {
    std::string cmd(ccmd);
    if (cmd == "dalsi") {
        if (ps.empty()) {
            std::printf("-1\n");
        } else {
            std::printf("%d\n", ps.top().ev_num);
            ps.pop();
        }
    } else if (cmd == "pacient") {
        std::scanf("%d%d\n", &ev_num, &ill_state);
        Pacient new_ps;
        new_ps.ev_num = ev_num;
        new_ps.ill_state = ill_state;
        ps.push(new_ps);
    } else if (cmd == "koniec") {
        break;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

After compiling and entering something to stdin, I have got following segfault:

```
       Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strlen_sse2_pminub () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-sse2-pminub.S:38
38  ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-sse2-pminub.S: No such file or directory.
```

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit.
Could somebody please explain, what caused the problem?

**Note: I am using scanf instead of cin, because I have specific instruction (from school) to use scanf, printf instead of cin, cout. I wouldn't use it otherwise.**

Comment: `scanf` expects a `char *` when you use "%s". That said, use a `std::string` and `operator>>` or `std::getline`.

Comment: @Aashish Yes, I could, but I have specific instruction for this code to use scanf and printf.

Comment: @chris I am using it already.

Comment: Your title is completely off base: you are *not* reading into a `std::string` using `scanf`, you are attempting to read a `char *`, *which is a c-style string*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare some storage for `scanf` to write into:

```
char ccmd[1000];
```

Otherwise, `*ccmd` is a random pointer with (probably) not enough storage for the characters to be written to.   Note that `scanf` does not do indirection on that space.

Also, `ccmd` is already a pointer, so the extra `&` (address of) is not needed:

```
 std::scanf("%s", ccmd)
```

Comment: To protect against stack overflow: `std::scanf("%999s", ccmd)`

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin:  updated to address (somewhat more elegantly).

Comment: Are you sure that `*` allows you to specify the maximum field width? Also, field width for `%s` should not include space for `\0`, i.e. `sizeof ccmd - 1`.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin:  Oh, you are quite right.  Retracted.

Comment: @wallyk I wish it did allow that though (.

Answer (score 0):

You did not initilaize pointer `ccmd`

```
char* ccmd;
```

and did not allocate memory where you are going to read a string

```
while (std::scanf("%s", &ccmd)) {
```

SO the program has undefined behaviour.

It is totally unclear why you do not want to use operator >> with stream `std::cin` and instead you use unsafe function scanf.

Also you need include header `<string>`. Otherwise if you will try to compile your program with other compilers you can get an error message.

And as pointed out  **@Maxim Yegorushkin** even the call of function scanf is incorrrect. Instead of

```
std::scanf("%s", &ccmd)
```

There should be

```
std::scanf("%s", ccmd)
```

Comment: Please could you be more specific? E.g. exactly how to initialize that pointer?

Comment: @Benji It has to refer to allocated memory where you are going to read in a string. Now this pointer has some arbitrary value.

Comment: You pass `char**` into `%s` format, which is not correct.

Comment: But you can do `sscanf("%ms", &ccmd)` and it will allocate a buffer for you when using glibc. It is a non-standard extension.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `std::scanf` to read strings, you can use safe C++:

```
std::string cmd;
while(std::cin >> cmd) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I have specific instruction (from school) to use scanf and printf in this code.

Comment: @Benji this is rather strange that they ask you to use C++ and C-style input/output.

Comment: I heard it's because input to this program will be very large, and scanf should be faster than cin.

Comment: @Benji oh no, milliseconds wasted! Seriously, they should teach you proper idiomatic C++ code, *then* worry about performance.

Comment: @Benji Please note that `scanf` family of functions is prone to introduce stack overflows into your application, like `scanf("%s")` definitely does because you don't specify the maximum string length to read. In other words, `scanf` family of functions is harder to use correctly.