# Unable to read and print consecutive strings using %s in C

Tags: c

I want to take string using the `%s` from the user and the base address will be stored in a character pointer. I want to take input like the above for two consecutive strings. For the first string it took the input correctly but from the second the segmentation fault occurred. I have tried for the three consecutive strings which is given below, but same problem occurred from the second string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() 
{
    char *s1, *s2, *s3;

    printf("Enter the first string: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", s1);
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("%s\n", s1);

    printf("Enter the second string: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", s2);
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("%s\n", s2);

    printf("Enter the third string: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", s3);
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("%s\n", s3);
    return 0;
}
```

Now what will be the solution without using the static initialization of character arrays?

Comment: The `scanf` functions doesn't allocate memory for you. The pointers you pass to it must actually point somewhere valid. Any books, tutorial, or class should have mentioned it.

Comment: Also note that the C specification explicitly mention that calling `fflush` with an input-only stream (like `stdin`) leads to *undefined behavior*. Of the big three compilers, only one single compiler and standard library combination have it as a non-standard and non-portable extension. Just don't use it, and any learning resource that teaches it should be looked at with  lot of suspicion.

Comment: Some standard library implementations have exactly the required feature — dynamic allocation for input strings. Unfortunately, this is not standard; I have never used it. [`scanf("%ms", &s1)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11926883/509868)

Comment: Didn't your compiler complain about using variables without assigning a value first?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Segmentation fault when reading C-style string from scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077979/segmentation-fault-when-reading-c-style-string-from-scanf)

Answer (score 4):

> I want to take string using the %s from the user and the base address will be stored in a character pointer.

That's not how `scanf` works.  There is no base address for data read from an input stream, and `scanf` does not choose one (that is, it does not allocate memory dynamically).  Nor could `scanf` store an address in the provided pointer anyway, because C passes all arguments by value.  `scanf` receives only the address already stored in the pointer, with no way to change that.

What `scanf` actually does is store the data it reads in the space to which the corresponding pointer argument points.  This is the same for all conversion specifiers that store anything.  *You* must choose the base address, and ensure that it points to space large enough to accommodate the input.  And because user-provided string input for `%s` can be arbitrarily long, you should specify a maximum field width sufficient to ensure that the provided space is not overrun (including by the string terminator that `scanf` will provide automatically).  Example:

```
    char s1[100];

    printf("Enter the first string: ");
    scanf("%99s", s1);
```

**Side note about `fflush()`**

`fflush()` ensures that *output* to the specified stream that remains buffered in memory is sent to the corresponding output device.  Its effect on a stream that is open only for input is undefined.  Thus,

- it should not be used at all on streams open only for input;
- it should not be assumed to have any particular effect on the input side of a stream open for both input and output; and
- it is not useful (but not harmful either) to use it on an output stream to which nothing has yet been written.

Answer (score 2):

#### Issue with `fflush(stdin)`

Using `fflush(stdin)` in your code can lead to undefined behavior.
This function is intended for output stream buffers like `stdout`, not for input streams like `stdin`.
Applying `fflush` on `stdin` might cause unpredictable results or program crashes.

For more details, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/22902085/869330

#### Memory Allocation for Pointers

In your code, the pointers `s1`, `s2`, and `s3` are declared but not allocated any memory.
This means they point to random memory locations, leading to undefined behavior (like segmentation faults) when you try to read or write using `scanf` and `printf`.
To fix this, allocate memory to these pointers using `malloc` before using them in `scanf`.

```c
#include <stdlib.h> 
...
int main()
{
// (Variable declaration codes)
s1 = (char *)malloc(size * sizeof(char));
// (scanf codes)
free(s1);
return 0;
}
```

Here, `size` should be the maximum length of the string you expect to input (including the NULL at the end).
Remember to free the allocated memory at the end of your program to avoid memory leaks.

For more details, refer to [Storing a string in char pointer (using scanf)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71750722/869330) and study `malloc` and `free`.

> An uninitialized variable contains (generally) some random garbage number.

Comment: This is dangerous advice. `scanf` can overflow the allocated buffer (which has a fixed, limited size) and would then overwrite other memory, allowing attackers arbitrary code execution.

Comment: Why not show the more natural way, with plain arrays instead?

Answer (score 2):

Consider

```
char *s1; // s1 is uninitialized (value is indeterminate)
```

Now, pass that uninitialized value to scanf with:

```
scanf("%s", s1);
```

and you are essentially telling the compiler "at run time, read data from the input stream up until some whitespace (or end of file) and store the data at some unspecified, indeterminate, pseudo-random location in memory."

When you frame it that way, I think it's clear why it does not work well.

Answer (score 1):

try to put one space in your scanf before "%s"
scanf(" %s", string); //right

scanf("%s", string); //wrong

if don't work try this

scanf(" %[^\n]", string);

Answer (score 1):

Note these problems:

- To read an input word with `scanf`, you must pass the address of an *existing* buffer.  `char *s1;` defines a pointer, but this pointer is uninitialized, so it cannot be used as the destination of `scanf()` input until it is set to point to an actual buffer. For your example, simply define arrays such as `char s1[100];` and pass them to `scanf()`.
- `scanf("%s", s1)` is risky because any input wortd longer than the length of the destination array.  You should specify the maximum number of characters to store as `scanf("%99s", s1)`, assuming `s1` is or points to an array of 100 characters.
- `fflush(stdin)` has undefined behavior because `stdin` is open for input. You should use a different way to consume the pending input until the newline:

  ```
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        continue;
  ```

  But in the current case, *flushing* the pending input is not useful.
- also note that `%s` reads a **word**, ie: a sequence of characters up to an not including a whitespace character such as a space or a newline.  In the prompt, you request the user to input a **string**, so you should accept embedded whitespace.  You can achieve that with `%[\n]` instead of `%s` but beware that unlike `%s`, `%[\n]` does not skip initial pending whitespace, such as the newline entered at the end of the previous input.  Specify `" %[\n]"` (note the initial space) to skip the pending newline.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char s1[100], s2[100], s3[100];

    printf("Enter the first string: ");
    if (scanf(" %99[^\n]", s1) == 1)
        printf("%s\n", s1);

    printf("Enter the second string: ");
    if (scanf(" %99[^\n]", s2) == 1)
        printf("%s\n", s2);

    printf("Enter the third string: ");
    if (scanf(" %99[^\n]", s3) == 1)
        printf("%s\n", s3);
    return 0;
}
```